# Не запускается fail2ban: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

Ubuntu 16.04.
Остановился fail2ban и не желает запускаться:

```
# systemctl start fail2ban
Job for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
# systemctl status fail2ban.service
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 01 18:46:32 dedic.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Как я понял fail2ban в процессе работы забанил слишком много (больше чем start-limit-hit). Поэтому не хочет запускаться.

Вопросы:

Как очистить все правила блокировки для запуска fail2ban?

Как можно увеличить число start-limit-hit?

Comment: Не оно? https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=293796.15

Comment: нет. Те ребята предлагают тупо переустановить. А мне бы разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Ковырялся вчера в поисках ответов. Случайно наткнулся на

```
# fail2ban-client -x start
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/vesta/auth.log
```

Вспомнил, что чистил логи. А указанный лог не создался автоматически после перезагрузки. Создал его вручную, fail2ban запустился.

Остается непонятным вывод сообщения "Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'"...